# Results.Ok(output) versus Results.Ok(await output.ToArrayAsync())

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, minimal-apis

If I use

```cs
// VERSION A
private static IResult Gets(AppDbContext db)
{
    var output = db.Courses.AsNoTracking().Select(c => new CourseDto { Id = c.Id, Credits = c.Credits });
    return Results.Ok(output);
}
```

instead of

```cs
// VERSION B
private static async Task<IResult> Gets(AppDbContext db)
{
    var output = db.Courses.AsNoTracking().Select(c => new CourseDto { Id = c.Id, Credits = c.Credits });
    return Results.Ok(await output.ToArrayAsync());
}
```

does the framework internally invoke one of  `ToArray()`, `ToArrayAsync()`, `ToList()` or `ToListAsync()`, etc (among others) to "materialize" `IQueryable<CourseDto>` and produce JSON output?

One more question: Which approach should I choose? Version A or version B?

Comment: It's not going to be able to create JSON from an IQueryable without materializing the query results.  So your first one is effectively `return Results.Ok(output.ToArray());` (or `ToList()`).  It's at that point that your query is executed.  If you explicitly use `.ToArrayAsync()`, then you are doing the query asynchronously and you get all the goodness that comes from async operations.  Choosing the **B**lue pill here is the correct course of action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not going to be able to create JSON from an `IQueryable` without materializing the query results.

So your first one is effectively `return Results.Ok(output.ToArray());` (or `ToList()`) (well, it's likely cheaper than either `ToArray` or `ToList` - it's really just the cost of `foreach`ing through the data). It's at that point that your query is executed.

If you explicitly use `.ToArrayAsync()`, then you are doing the query asynchronously and you get all the goodness that comes from async operations. Choosing the **B**lue pill here is the correct course of action

If you don't make the `async` call explicitly, I'm pretty sure the query is going to be done synchronously. Without an `async` notation, the compiler can't build the scaffolding to support asynchronous operations. Remember, async requires async all the way down the stack

Answer (score 0):

I'm no C# expert, but version B seems functionally the same as version A.  `await`-ing an async method in this scenario accomplishes the same thing as just calling the synchronous method.  I'd keep it simple & just use version A.

I don't believe this method will return JSON - just an IQueryable.  I believe you can do:

```cs
private static IResult Gets(AppDbContext db)
{
    var output = db.Courses.AsNoTracking().Select(c => new CourseDto { Id = c.Id, Credits = c.Credits });
    return Json(output);
}
```

You may need to change the return type to `ActionResult`

Comment: I am not sure whether the passed `output` of type  `IQuerayble<CourseDto>` will be materialized synchronously or asynchronously in `Results.Ok()`. It is one of aspects that I want to know.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the query is going to be done synchronously.  Without an `async` notation, the compiler can't build the scaffolding to support asynchronous operations.  Remember, `async` requires `async` all the way down the stack